# How to use 2 different google API's in one Android project?

Tags: android, google-geolocation

As I mention, I was trying to use two different google API's in my project,
the first one is the [Google GeoLoaction Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#overview), and the second is [AutoComplete Api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget).
the problem is, they both need the key to at the Manifest.xml in the Application meta-data, but when I tried adding both, the second key override the first one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

</application>
```

I tried also to add another String in my values, It didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Autocomplete` and `GeoLocation` Api's can be used with the same Api Key.You need to add the key only once in your `Manifest`.You just need to enable the required Api's in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com).